# Abort operation if it does not succeed in 1 minute

Tags: java

The following code is supposed to send an SMS to a mobile phone and return if the operation succeeds. It should abort the operation and try sending another message if the oeration does not succeed in more than 1 minute. The code runs fine in test environments but when it's implemented in the production environment it seems to wait forever until the operation succeeds ignoring the 60 second rule. If anyone could spot any problem in the workings  of the code, I would like you to tell me.

```
public synchronized String sendSms(MessageData messageData) {

    class Task implements Callable<String> {

        private MessageData messageData;

        public Task(MessageData messageData) {
            this.messageData = messageData;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {

            System.out.println("Sending MPT >>> " + "Number : " + messageData.getToAddress() + ", Message : "
                    + messageData.getMessage());

            SendSMS.send(messageData.getToAddress(), messageData.getMessage(),
                    Long.toString(messageData.getSyskey()));

            //The real code that sends the message
            //***

            return "1";
        }
    }

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Task t = new Task(messageData);
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(t);

    try {
        System.out.println("Started..");
        future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();
        return "1";
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdown();
        return "-1";
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        executor.shutdown();
        return "-1";
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        executor.shutdown();
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess I have to digest on that; but one immediate thought: using "-1" resp. "1" as return value? Really? Seriously: thats bad.

Comment: You're saying it hangs on `future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this at all?   If so, what were the results.   For example try putting break points just before and after the call to Future.get(long, TimeUnit) and to confirm that (a) at last one thread actually gets to the print statement, and (b) that same thread does NOT get to executor.shutdown().

Comment: I guess the async thread is blocked at the `SendSMS.send(...)` call.  If you were to use `shutdownNow()` instead of `shutdown()` the executor would attempt to interrupt the executing thread before shutting down (i.e. "best effort") but whether this works or not depends on the SMS library you're using.  If that `send()` is not interruptible then there's no way kill it other than shutting down the entire JVM.  You might get better help if you tell us exactly which SMS library you're using and what platform you're on.

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison we are using the proprietary SMS library we have developed. The library is well tested but the telcos it works with can exhibit strange behaviour sometimes hence the strange code that we have to use for our case.

Comment: When the sending code blocks at the lowest level, at the interface to the driver, is it interruptible?

Comment: @JimGarrison we are not integrating using drivers as such. We use the programming language APIs provided by local telcoms and their libraries can sometimes be faulty.

Comment: you are missing the crucial question.  Is the low-level API interruptible. If not then you are out of luck. If it is you can handle `InterruptedException` to do the cleanup.

Comment: @JimGarrison It may not be but I have the option of abandoning it running forever and tackling the next taks.

Comment: If it never ends you'll leak threads and memory. Otherwise just abandon the Callable.

Comment: Yes @JimGarrison. You have directed me in the right direction. You can't kill a thread if the operation in it doesn't respond to the request to stop. The thread can leak if it never ends. The service may have to be restarted on a weekly basis to reset leaked threads.

Answer (score 1):

This answer summarizes the information gleaned piecemeal in the comments.

The OP uses an API to send SMS messages. Each send is delegated to a normally short-lived thread implemented as a `Callable`.  Unfortunately the API's `send` functionality can block, apparently indefinitely.

When using an API that can block, three general cases exist:

1. The API "aware" of the JVM and is implemented so that it can respond to Java interruption exceptions and terminate its operation.
2. The API is not Java-aware but has a timeout option that will cause it to terminate and return after a specified time period.
3. The blocking operation may block indefinitely and is not interruptible by an action within the JVM.

Handling the first two cases is easy using standard Java techniques.

The OP's problem is that the API seems to be of the third type.  In this case, the `Callable` thread can be abandoned by the main thread after the 60 second timeout, but if the `send()` API call never returns the thread will never terminate.  This will result in permanent leakage of the thread and its resources (network port, memory, etc), which will require that the application be restarted regulary to reclaim leaked resources.